# Javascript variable to json in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a string look as javascript variable `'{name : "John" , age : 17}'` in Python, how I can convert it to JSON like this 

`{
    "name" : "John" ,
    "age" : 17
}`
 or how to add double quotes to field `name` and `age`. 
`json.loads` coudn`t help me, it return me string not json

Comment: What do you think the difference between JSON and a string is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this is a proper json - the keys in your example, `name` and `age`, are not surrounded with quotes, which is invalid data by itself.

If that is not the case, e.g. a typo in the question, the method to use is `dumps()`:

```
import json
py_dict = {"name": "John" , "age": 17}
json_val = json.dumps(py_dict)   # string json representation of the dictionary
json_val2 =json.dumps(json.loads('{"name" : "John" , "age" : 17}'))    # parsing a string as dictionary and then dumping it as a json-formatted string
```

As you can see by the 2nd example, `loads()` takes a json string and creates a dictionary out of it.

---

Answering the updated question: any attempt to parse and fix the source with string replace or regex is error prone.

As yaml is a superset of json, and your example does look like yaml, it might be able to parse it:

```
import yaml, json
val = '{name: "John" , age: 17}'
py_dict = yaml.loads(val)    # it is now a proper python dictionary
print(json.dumps(py_dict))
# prints 
#    {"name": "John" , "age": 17}
```

Comment: How can I add quotes to `name` and `age`? Because I have the only string such as `'{name : "John" , age : 17}'`

Comment: Updated my answer with how to parse the raw value